# Очень хитрые вопрошающие

Tags: обсуждение, дубликаты, удаление-вопросов

В последнее время заметил, что у некоторых вопрошающих появилась привычка пересоздавать вопросы.

То есть задал человек вопрос, на этот вопрос либо не обратили внимание, либо на него есть ответ, но вопрошающего он не удовлетворил, либо вопрос заминусовали; по прошествии нескольких часов/дней автор вопроса удаляет его (**со всеми ответами и комментариями**) и тут же создает новый такой же вопрос.

Как бороться с этим? И стоит ли с этим бороться?

Comment: Вроде как с ответами, у которых положительный баланс голосов, вопрос удалить нельзя. Но вообще, хорошо бы примеры ссылок, на финальные вопросы разумеется.

Comment: можно кидать тревогу модераторам со ссылкой на предыдущий вопрос

Comment: @Grundy так предыдущий удален :) Какая ссылка?

Comment: @alexolut, вот такая ссылка на удаленный вопрос :-) например в истории браузера могла сохраниться. В любом случае модераторы видят удаленные вопросы пользователей, поэтому могут проверить

Comment: Вот вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/580613/proxy-json-%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d1%83 Вчера я к нему же комментарий писал. Ссылки на первичный вопрос нет.

Comment: @Visman Вы лучше в свой вопрос ссылку добавьте из коммента.

Comment: @Grundy да я понимаю, что модераторы видят. Вопрос в том, как получить ссылку обычному участнику. Кстати при 10К+ только ответы удаленные видно или вопросы тоже?

Comment: @alexolut, и вопросы тоже/

Comment: @alexolut удалённые комментарии не видно. Вопросы и ответы не видно в списках (кроме кэша), но видно по прямым ссылкам.

Comment: Восстановил: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/580386/181472

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Нужно ставить **тревогу** с <kbd>требуется вмешательство модератора</kbd>  и пояснением, что автор недавно стёр такой же вопрос. По возможности, приложив ссылку на удалённый вопрос.

---

#### ...но после нескольких таких трюков система сама накажет нарушителя.

**Причём капитально и бессрочно.** Участник [потеряет возможность задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans), пока не принесёт пользу сообществу другими способами: например, реставрируя свои старые вопросы или публикуя другие полезные сообщения.

Уговоры и объяснения, что подобными действиями автор исключительно вредит сам себе, ненадёжны. А требуемые действия находятся вне зоны возможностей рядовых пользователей.

Comment: `Уговоры и объяснения, что подобными действиями автор исключительно вредит сам себе, ненадёжны` – они гораздо лучше, чем ничего. Даже ссылка на этот вопрос может принести пользу )

Comment: Допустим, но бывают и немного иные ситуации, как у меня: я задал вопрос где-то в 4 утра. Спустя пару часов его "сметает" потоком других вопросов, а днем я обнаруживаю, что вопрос увидело 2-3 человека. Вопрос я пересоздал, так как 2 дня для назначения награды ждать немного долго (ответ требуется как можно быстрее). Плохо ли это? Лично мое мнение таково: из-за потока сообщений вопросы "сметает" и они остаются не увиденными, такие вопросы стоит разрешить поднимать вверх списка новых вопросов, чтобы их заметили.

Comment: @RostislavDugin достаточно отредактировать вопрос. Желательно ещё при этом его улучшить.

Comment: @D-side, и он поднимется на верх?

Comment: @D-side, проблема в том, что вопрос содержательный и качественный (как минимум, я так считаю). Но не замечен он из-за отсутствия людей во время его появления, а не качества.

Comment: @RostislavDugin да, поднимется.

Comment: @RostislavDugin учтите, что многие отвечающие обосновываются в конкретных метках и периодически просматривают вопросы **только по ним**. У нас пока не настолько бешеная активность, чтобы с этих страниц вопросы сметались за пару часов.

Comment: @RostislavDugin, если вопрос долго (несколько суток) не получает должного внимания, думаю, можно бросить клич в [чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--).

Comment: @Arhad ага, и получить т. н. "Мета-эффект", обратный ожидаемому. :)

Comment: @D-side надо было упомянуть, что поднимается он на главной, а не на `/questions`. Хотя, как по мне, именно она (questions) главнее